# Unwanted image title in stack overflow talent pages

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-talent

There are some unwanted image title are visible in the Stack Overflow Talent pages. Inspect the image elements the title is set as  `title="xxxx.svg"`

In the right hand side top of the  [Blog](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/blog) page, the subscribe image having the unwanted image title as `subscribe.svg`.

[image: Subscribe]

In middle of the [About us](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/about) page, the news image having the unwanted image title as `news.svg`.

[image: News]

Hope these unwanted titles are need to be remove.